# How can I count and print duplicate strings in a string array in Java?

Tags: java

I have a dilemma on my hands. After much trial and error, I still could not figure out this simple task.

I have one array

```
String [] array = {anps, anps, anps, bbo, ehllo};
```

I need to be able to go through the array and find duplicates and print them on the same line. Words with no duplicates should be displayed alone

The output needs to be like this

```
anps anps anps
bbo
ehllo
```

I have tried while, for loops but the logic seems impossible.

Comment: It's not impossible--hang in there. What have you tried?

Comment: One way would be using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where the key is the word, and the value is the counter.

Comment: Trust me, when I say I have tried. Its been 4 hrs since I started. I have tried using a for loop then putting an if statement inside the for loop to check if array[i]==array[i+1], but even if its equal, I can't say string+=array[i] + " " + array[i+1];

Comment: ay pacman, its not like am a freeloader; I have tried everything but I still can't do it, I just need a little help.

Comment: Oh wow, looking at the posts here we are getting a worrying number of incorrect answers.

Comment: @Bob Owuor how will be the output if the input is String [] array = {anps, anps, anps, bbo, ehllo, anps};

Comment: I meant, basically working on the string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array first then

```
for(int i = 0, i < array.length; i++){
    String temp = array[i];
    System.out.print(temp+" ");
    for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
        String temp2 = array[j];
        if(temp.compareTo(temp2) == 0){
            System.out.print(temp2+" ");
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

or something similar...

Comment: if I do this on `{a, a, a, b}`
I will print out
`a a a, a a, a, b`

Comment: did you actually try it or are you assuming?

Comment: I believe you missed my i++ inside the nested for loop

Comment: haha I wasn't entirely sure about the syntax behind that...but you still missed my i++

Comment: I changed it to compareTo which is what I should have been using to begin with, correct?

Comment: I missed the i++; this is one way of doing it, but this is not the most optimal solution.

Comment: if you have an array of n distinct values, this method takes O(n^2)

Answer (score 10):

Okay, there are a worryingly number of either wrong answers or answers that use `HashMap` or `HashSet` for this very simple iteration problem, so here is a correct solution.

```
Arrays.sort(array);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    if (i+1 == array.length) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    } else if (array[i].equals(array[i+1])) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution...easy and efficient.

Comment: Hans in the future to not muck things up too much it's best to just edit your previous answer

Comment: @KendallFrey this only works if the array is sorted, the poster didn't specify that the array started off sorted.

Comment: @NominSim my previous answer has nothing in common with my current one. I've already deleted my first answer.

Comment: Well, it depends what `a, b, a` should print.

Comment: Sorry Hans didn't see that it was deleted.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Man your way of solving this is crazy. Its still boggling my mind, that's why I came back after all this time. Thanks so much man.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

1. Use two for loops, one that loops through the array and picks a value and another inner loop where you go through the array (from the current index) looking for that value
2. You could have a map that contains the words, you loop through the array and you fill out the map with the number of occurrences corresponding to the value currently fetched from the array

The second way is better. The code is something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int index=0; index < array.length; index++){
       int nOcc = 1;
       if(occurences.containsKey(array[index]){
         nOcc = occurences.get(array[index]) + 1;
       }
       occurences.remove(array[index]);
       occurences.put(array[index], nOcc);
}
```

At this point, the map should contain all words (keys) and their corresponding number of occurrences (values)

Comment: if I do `1.` on `{a, b, a, a}` I'll get the following:

`a a a, b, a a, a`

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the array first, then you can just check if the current index is equal to the next index (bearing in mind that you must account for `IndexOutOfBounds`), if they are equal do a `System.out.print()` if they are not equal do a `System.Out.println()`.

```
String [] array = {"anps", "anps", "anps", "bbo", "ehllo"};
// If you already are assured that the strings in the array are sorted
// then the sort is not necessary. 
Arrays.sort(array);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if((i+1)==array.length || !array[i].equals(array[(i+1)])){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: But what do you mean, do a system.out.print. What is your advise, should I print [i] or [i+1]?

Comment: @BobOwuor `System.out.print` prints the value without the line end, whereas `System.out.println` adds the line end. I update my answer with code that should work.

Comment: @BobOwuor What isn't it doing? This works according to the question AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity `n^2` , just start from first value and go to the end finding the same, if you found print in one line and go to the new line, also you should delete all printed value.

Complexity `nlogn + n` == `nlogn` , `merge` or `quick` sort, and after this go to the end and pring sequenced values.
There are more solutions but I think its enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Naive Algorithms

- Create a Map
- Iterate through all array
- check if key already exist in map
- if yes update value +1
- if no insert
- print the map as you want

You should be able to do what you're looking for !

Answer (score 0):

### Use below logic

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RepeatStringPrint {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String[] x = { "anps", "anps", "anps", "bbo", "ehllo" };
            String total[] = new String[50];
            String sTotal[] = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                total[i] = x[i];
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < total.length; k++) {
                int count = 0;
                if (total[k] != null) {
                    sTotal = new String[50];
                    for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
                        if (total[k] == total[i]) {
                            count++;
                            if (count <= 1) {
                                sTotal[i] = total[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (sTotal[k] != null) {
                        for(int j=0; j<count; j++){
                            System.out.print(sTotal[k]+"\t");
                        }
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```